# How to proceed JSON empty object in Retrofit 2.0 response?

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit2

Here is an example of json response. As you can see fields like: news, number_likes, number_comment, number_post, user, owner are always present. But fields like: place, place_mark, comment, album, photo are not always present. It depends on type of news.

```
{
"result": true,
"news_list": [
{
"news": {
"id": "67",
"text": "",
"text_post": "",
"date_create": "1460321713"
},
"number_likes": "0",
"number_comment": "0",
"number_post": "0",
"user": {
"id": "41",
"name": "Jimmy",
"last_name": "",
"avatar": "http://base_url/userPhotos/41/album/original/08382.jpeg",
"last_activity": "1460035798"
},
"owner": {
"id": "41",
"name": "Jimmy",
"last_name": "",
"avatar": "http://base_url/userPhotos/41/album/original/08382.jpeg",
"last_activity": "1460035798"
},
"place": {
"id": "1",
"name": "test",
"avatar": ""
},
"place_mark": {
"id": "1",
"date_create": "1460321699"
}
},
{
"news": {
"id": "66",
"text": "",
"text_post": "",
"date_create": "1460321623"
},
"number_likes": "0",
"number_comment": "0",
"number_post": "0",
"user": {
"id": "41",
"name": "Jimmy",
"last_name": "",
"avatar": "http://base_url/userPhotos/41/album/original/08382.jpeg",
"last_activity": "1460035798"
},
"owner": {
"id": "41",
"name": "Jimmy",
"last_name": "",
"avatar": "http://base_url/userPhotos/41/album/original/08082.jpeg",
"last_activity": "1460035798"
},
"place": {
"id": "1",
"name": "test",
"avatar": ""
},
"comment": {
"id": "1",
"parent_id": "",
"text": "qwer",
"rating": "0",
"date_create": "1460321472"
},
"photos": []
},
{
"news": {
"id": "65",
"text": "new news",
"text_post": "",
"date_create": "1460320767"
},
"number_likes": "0",
"number_comment": "0",
"number_post": "0",
"user": {
"id": "41",
"name": "Jimmy",
"last_name": "",
"avatar": "http://base_url/userPhotos/41/album/original/08082.jpeg",
"last_activity": "1460035798"
},
"owner": {
"id": "41",
"name": "Jimmy",
"last_name": "",
"avatar": "http://base_url/userPhotos/41/album/original/0882.jpeg",
"last_activity": "1460035798"
},
"photos": [
{
"photo": {
"id": "84",
"name": "",
"filename": "2d20f883cb023a1ff14f32d0ee79a02c.jpeg",
"mime_type": "image/jpeg",
"height": "540",
"width": "442",
"link": "http://base_url/userPhotos/41/album/original/29a02c.jpeg"
}
},
{
"photo": {
"id": "85",
"name": "",
"filename": "2d20f883cb023a1ff14f32d0ee79a02c.jpeg",
"mime_type": "image/jpeg",
"height": "540",
"width": "442",
"link": "http://base_url/userPhotos/41/album/original/2d20f2c.jpeg"
}
}
]
},
{
"news": {
"id": "64",
"text": "",
"text_post": "",
"date_create": "1460320759"
},
"number_likes": "0",
"number_comment": "0",
"number_post": "0",
"user": {
"id": "41",
"name": "Jimmy",
"last_name": "",
"avatar": "http://base_url/userPhotos/41/album/original/0809fb.jpeg",
"last_activity": "1460035798"
},
"owner": {
"id": "41",
"name": "Jimmy",
"last_name": "",
"avatar": "http://base_url/userPhotos/41/album/original/0882.jpeg",
"last_activity": "1460035798"
},
"album": {
"id": "34",
"name": "asdfgh",
"description": "",
"position": ""
},
"photo": ""
}
]
}
```

this is my model for this response:

```
public class GetNewsResponse {

private String result;

private List<NewsList> news_list;

private Errors errors;

public String getResult() {
    return result;
}

public List<NewsList> getNews_list() {
    return news_list;
}

public Errors getErrors() {
    return errors;
}


public class NewsList {

    private String number_likes;

    private String number_comment;

    private String number_post;

    private News news;

    private User user;

    private Owner owner;

    private Place place;

    private PlaceMark place_mark;

    private Comment comment;

    private Album album;

    private List<Photo2> photos;

    public String getNumber_likes() {
        return number_likes;
    }

    public String getNumber_comment() {
        return number_comment;
    }

    public String getNumber_post() {
        return number_post;
    }

    public News getNews() {
        return news;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public Owner getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public Place getPlace() {
        return place;
    }

    public PlaceMark getPlaceMark() {
        return place_mark;
    }

    public Comment getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public Album getAlbum() {
        return album;
    }

    public List<Photo2> getPhotos() {
            return photos;
    }
}


public class News {

    private String id;

    private String text;

    private String text_post;

    private String date_create;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public String getDate_create() {
        return date_create;
    }

    public String getText_post() {
        return text_post;
    }
}

public class User {

    private String id;

    private String name;

    private String last_name;

    private String avatar;

    private String last_activity;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getLast_name() {
        return last_name;
    }

    public String getAvatar() {
        return avatar;
    }

    public String getLast_activity() {
        return last_activity;
    }

}

public class Owner {

    private String id;

    private String name;

    private String last_name;

    private String avatar;

    private String last_activity;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getLast_name() {
        return last_name;
    }

    public String getAvatar() {
        return avatar;
    }

    public String getLast_activity() {
        return last_activity;
    }
}

public class Place {

    private String id;

    private String name;

    private String avatar;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAvatar() {
        return avatar;
    }
}

public class PlaceMark {

    private String id;

    private String date_create;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getDate_create() {
        return date_create;
    }
}

public class Comment {

    private String id;

    private String parent_id;

    private String text;

    private String rating;

    private String date_create;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getParent_id() {
        return parent_id;
    }

    public String getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public String getDate_create() {
        return date_create;
    }
}

public class Album {

    private String id;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    private String position;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public String getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

}

public class Photo2 {

    private Object photo;

    public Object getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }
}

public class Photo {

    private String id;

    private String name;

    private String filename;

    private String mime_type;

    private String height;

    private String width;

    private String link;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getFilename() {
        return filename;
    }

    public String getMime_type() {
        return mime_type;
    }

    public String getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public String getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }
}

public class Errors {

    private String text;

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

}
}
```

This is my api method implementation:

```
public void getNewsMethod() {
sm.getNews(user_id, limit, offset, photo_size, avatar_size, all, new Callback(){

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<GetNewsResponse> call, Response<GetNewsResponse> response) {
            List<GetNewsResponse.NewsList> list = response.body().getNews_list();
            instantiateAdapter(list);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<GetNewsResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MyNewsActivity.this, "get news failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

I use retrofit 2.0.1 and native GSonConverterFactory:

```
private static Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
.baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
```

And this is my error at json deserializing when photos json array is empty:

com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 9480 path $.news_list[11].photos[0].photo

Please help me! What I need to do for proper json deserialization? Maybe anybody has experience in writing custom converter factory or can give me any suggestions according to my problem? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a loot at your json response. There is a problem in the last NewsList object.

```
{
"news": {
"id": "64",
"text": "",
"text_post": "",
"date_create": "1460320759"
},
"number_likes": "0",
"number_comment": "0",
"number_post": "0",
"user": {
"id": "41",
"name": "Jimmy",
"last_name": "",
"avatar": "http://base_url/userPhotos/41/album/original/0809fb.jpeg",
"last_activity": "1460035798"
},
"owner": {
"id": "41",
"name": "Jimmy",
"last_name": "",
"avatar": "http://base_url/userPhotos/41/album/original/0882.jpeg",
"last_activity": "1460035798"
},
"album": {
"id": "34",
"name": "asdfgh",
"description": "",
"position": ""
},
"photo": "" // <- the problem
}
```

You should receive a list o photos, according to your specification. But you received a tag photo with a string. Please, check your web service.